# Is there an OpenZeppelin like library for Cardano?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, dev-container

Developers on EVM compatible blockchains can make use of battle-tested libraries of smart contracts using https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts

I'm thinking about having a basic functionality, let's say a base auction contract and then the developer can add/modify whatever he/she needs for his/her specific use case.

Is there something similar on Cardano or a base repo with Plutus Smart Contracts on it for us to take a look?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official or adopted standard library in Cardano, yet, as it is on Ethereum.

Anyway, in my opinion the best tools and techniques for Plutus can be found in this repo: https://github.com/Plutonomicon

It belongs to [MLabs](https://mlabs.city/), a Haskell, Rust, Blockchain and AI consultancy that has built more than 30 projects in Cardano.

There is also more information about their tools here: https://plutonomicon.github.io/plutonomicon/

Answer (score 0):

You can find reference plutus implementations here on github that can be used as a starting point:

https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-use-cases/src/Plutus/Contracts

You can also look at the cardano essential list and hopefully there will be more open source projects that you can also reference in the future.

https://github.com/input-output-hk/essential-cardano/blob/main/essential-cardano-list.md